# SQL select id=1

Tags: sql, categories

I've a table that has `id_categoria` field having comma separated value, e.g., `1,2,3,4,64,31,12,14`, because a record can belong to multiple categories. If I want to select records that belongs to category `1`,  I have to run following SQL query

```
SELECT * 
FROM cme_notizie 
WHERE id_categoria LIKE '1%' 
ORDER BY `id` ASC
```

and then select all records from the record set that have `id_categoria` exactly `1` in `id_categoria`. Let's assume that the value `1` does not exist, but column value like 12, 15, 120 ... still contains `1`.
There is a way to take only 1? without taking derivatives or other?

Comment: Argh, normalize your database.  Don't put multiple values in a single column.

Comment: Are you saying id_categoria contains a comma-separated string?

Comment: Here's a question that explains why keeping multiple categories in a column is a bad idea. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3653462/is-storing-a-delimited-list-in-a-database-column-really-that-bad  The #1 reason is exactly what you're running into right now.

Comment: So what is the correct method for my needs?

Comment: You should use an intermediate table containing `notizie` `categoria` association

Comment: create a new table with 2 columns, one column for `id_item` and the second one for `id_categoria`. Then you can have as many records for a single `id_item` as many categories it belongs to. I think it is called `one to many` relationship

Comment: Horrible for performance (use integers instead of strings). Please use "M:N" relationship (with additional table).

Answer (score 1):

As comments say, you probably shouldn't do that. Instead, you should have another table with one row per category. But if you decide to go with this inferior solution, you can do the following:

```
SELECT * 
FROM cme_notizie 
WHERE CONCAT(',', id_categoria, ',') LIKE '%,1,%' 
ORDER BY id ASC
```